# How to pass an array/pointer to HLS IP in SDK

Tags: sdk, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

Folks,
 
I need help on how I can pass an array/pointer to HLS IP in SDK. I know that if it is a scalar value I can use <>_get/set(*Instance) function but how to do it when you want to pass a memory region as array/pointer. I tired the following with no success.

```
#define DRAM_ADDR 0x00100000
u32 val;
u32* DRAM = (u32*)DRAM_ADDR;
XSimple_ddr simple_ddr;
int* res_hw;
memcpy(DRAM, data, 100*sizeof(int)); //data is an array with 100 elements

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   xil_printf("\nRead Memory: %d, %d, %d\n", res_hw[i], DRAM[i], DRAM[i+100]);
}
XSimple_ddr_Set_DRAM(&simple_ddr, DRAM);
XSimple_ddr_Set_num(&simple_ddr, 100);
if (XSimple_ddr_IsReady(&simple_ddr))
   print("HLS peripheral is ready. Starting... ");
else {
   print("!!! HLS peripheral is not ready! Exiting...\n\r");
   exit(-1);
}
XSimple_ddr_Start(&simple_ddr);
print("Detected HLS peripheral complete. Result received.\n\r");
do {
   res_hw = (int*)XSimple_ddr_Get_DRAM(&simple_ddr);
} while (!XSimple_ddr_IsReady(&simple_ddr));
xil_printf("------------------Read after IP------------------------\n");
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   xil_printf("\nRead Memory: %d, %d, %d", (res_hw[i]), DRAM[i], DRAM[i+100]);

}
```

The IP is:

```
void simple_ddr(int* DRAM, int num)
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE m_axi port=DRAM depth=400 offset=slave bundle=DRAMBUS register
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=num bundle=CONFIGBUS register
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=return bundle=CONFIGBUS register

int BRAM[100];
int j;
memcpy(BRAM, DRAM, num*sizeof(int));
int val=0;
for(j=0; j<num; j++)
{
    BRAM[j]=7 + val;
    val++;
}
memcpy(DRAM+num, BRAM, num*sizeof(int));
```

}

So what I observed is that the following line returns the base address of the DDR and the memory region starting from (base address + num) doesn't have the modifies data from the HLS IP.

```
res_hw = (int*)XSimple_ddr_Get_DRAM(&simple_ddr);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Forgive me if these are silly questions, but how did you come up with the 0x00100000 address? Does the SDK process and the IP share the same address space?

Comment: You can see that in the system.hdf file in SDK.

Comment: Do you see any change in the DRAM following the invocation of the IP? Do you have any other indication that it executes?

Comment: What sort of change are you referring to? I am able to write and read from it, the problem I have is passing a memory region to the IP for certain computation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after calling XSimple_ddr_Start, you expect the DRAM+100 region to be modified by the IP, but it doesn't contain the expected values. I'm asking whether that buffer changes at all following the invocation of the IP.

Comment: I see. For now the way I am checking that is, by reading the memory region after the IP is done its computation. How else would you check that from SDK unless you insert ILA in the design?

Comment: One way you can check that the IP does run is perhaps adding another output to the AXI lite bus and verifying that it gets updated with the correct value.